# Need Macro to add comma to the beginning of text string

Tags: excel, vba

I need a macro to append a comma onto the beginning of a column of text strings.  I recorded the action myself, but it limited itself to Column C (often, the text strings I need to do this with appear in a different column), and also limited the application of the range to the specific number of rows in the worksheet I recorded it on (in this case, 114).

Here is the original Record Macro output:

```
Sub AddCommaToESIID()
'
' AddCommaToESIID Macro
'

'
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Columns("E:E").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("C2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ","
    Range("C2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C2:C114")
    Range("C2:C114").Select
    Range("E2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]&RC[-1]"
    Range("E2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("E2:E114")
    Range("E2:E114").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("D2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=False
    Columns("E:E").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
End Sub
```

I would like to modify this to achieve the following:

1. Make the macro apply to whatever Column I have selected, as opposed to Column C
2. Once I have selected a Column, make the macro apply to however many rows there are in the particular worksheet I'm working on.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: If you have Office 365 use the worksheet formula,TextJoin().  If not search for that and you will find many vba UDFs that mimic the use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will change all non-formulas in whatever range you select

```
Sub AddCommaToESIID()

    Dim rCell As Range

    If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
        For Each rCell In Selection.Cells
            If Not rCell.HasFormula Then
                rCell.Value = "," & rCell.Value
            End If
        Next rCell
    End If

End Sub
```